# Import variables from bash to R

Tags: r

If I have this variable in bash:

```
sample='sampleA'
export $sample
```

How can I use it in R?

```
read.table('/home/"$sample"/file.txt')
```

I don't find a module similar to `os` in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case:

```
sample = Sys.getenv(c("sample"))
```

Usage:
    Sys.getenv(c("VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3", ... , "VARN"))